# How to use requests library to send data to the server?

Tags: python, http, server, binary, python-requests

The working process is I send a ticket to the server, the server will respond with information I need. For example,

```
import requests
URL = "https://ssl.XXX.com/sql_v5i.php"
Ticket = {"A":"1","B":"2"}  # a dictionary
ticket_post = requests.post(URL, data=Ticket)
print ticket__post.text
```

But how to send the Ticket with `"A":"1", "B":"2"` and binary data (with only data and no key) all at once ? If I only send the binary data, I can use "files". But how to send all this information all together to the server? Intuitively, it will more like this (but obviously it will not work):

```
import requests
URL = "https://ssl.XXX.com/sql_v5i.php"
Ticket = {"A":"1","B":"2","1010110111100110...101010"} 
ticket_post = requests.post(URL, data=Ticket)
print ticket__post.text
```

To comolete this task, there is piece of php works:

```
<?php

$BASE_SERVER_URL="https://ssl.XXX.com/sql_v5i.php"
$TICKET = array(
          'fn' => 'ticket',
          'testid' => '2'
          ... # And many other key-value pair in the TICKET array
          );    

class DataStreamer{
  private $data;
  private $pos;

function __construct($data) {
  $this->data = $data;
  $this->pos = 0;
}

function stream_function($handle, $fd, $count){
$res = substr($this->data, $this->pos, $count);
$this->pos += strlen($res);
return $res;
}
}

function sendTicketToServer($data) {
global $TICKET, $BASE_SERVER_URL; # TICKET is an array stores ticket           
                                  #  information in php
$ret = array(true);  
$postFields = "";
foreach ($TICKET as $name => $val)
    $postFields = (empty($postFields) ? "" :  "${postFields}&") ."${name}=" . urlencode($val); 

$ch = curl_init(); 

curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );  
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, "${BASE_SERVER_URL}?" . $postFields );  
                                        # add key-value pairs
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, false );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE );

 if (!empty($data)) { # data is the binary string , add binary string
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true); 
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true); 
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: application/octet-stream', 'Content-length: ' . strlen($data))); 
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_READFUNCTION, array(new DataStreamer($data), "stream_function")); 
    } else {
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: application/octet-stream', 'Content-length: 0')); 
}

$resp = curl_exec($ch);
$code=curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
if( $resp === FALSE || $code !== 200 ) {
    echo "!!!!! Failed to get connection from the server. Code:    $code\n";
    return array(ERR_NO_SERVER_CONNECTION."000");
}

curl_close($ch); 
return $ret;
```

How to do the same this in Python (using Requests or not are both acceptable).

Answer (score 1):

It is not really the problem of requests module. If we consider that you can send any kind of data structure using requests, you will have to find such a data structure that allows you to reference your data using a key and if the key is not provided it would return the binary data as a default value. 
Unfortunately python dictionary does not allow this, because there is a common agreement that in dictionary we reference the data using keys.

EDIT: You could probably start by using the actual implementation of dict

```
class kldict(dict):
    def __init__(self, default, *args, **kwargs):
        self.store = dict()
        self.update(dict(*args, **kwargs))
        self.default = default

    def update(self, *args, **kwargs):
        for k, v in dict(*args, **kwargs).iteritems():
            self.store[self.__keytransform__(k)] = v

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self.store[self.__keytransform__(key)] = value

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        del self.store[self.__keytransform__(key)]

    def __getitem__(self, key=None):
        if key:
            return self.store[self.__keytransform__(key)]
        else:
            return self.default

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.store)

    def __keytransform__(self, key):
        return key

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.default
```

Sample usage would be something like this:

```
var = kldict('0111010110110', {'C': 'D'})
var['B'] = 'G'
print(var['B'])
print(var['C'])
print(var[None])
print(var)
```

Which results in:

```
G
D
0111010110110
0111010110110
```

Comment: right, it doesn't has to be a dictionary in this case, just want to know how to send data with key and without key at one ticket.

Answer (score 0):

This question has too little detail to answer accurately, but here's an attempt anyway.

It *seems* as though you want to send data formatted like this to the server:

```
A=1&B=2&1010110111100110...101010
```

If that's the case, Requests has *no* way of doing that for you. It only handles the *most common* use-cases. Assuming that is the format you want, however, you *must* provide the string yourself, like so:

```
import urllib.parse

import requests

data = urllib.parse.urlencode({'A': '1', 'B': '2'}) + '1010110111100110...101010'
response = requests.post(url, data=data)
```

That said, if you don't specify a `Content-Type` it's possible that the website won't understand the data you've sent. When using this form, you *may* need to also pass

```
headers={'Content-Type': '...'}
```

To `requests.post`. I use `...` because it's unclear to me what `Content-Type` that website is expecting.